# Query DB Laravel

Tags: sql, laravel

I'm trying to count the post count of each tag, then **orderBy** by the **post count**.
But there was a problem when counting the number of posts: **tags with no posts were not displayed**.
I want if any tag has no post, it will still be printed. What should I do.

```
    $query = DB::table('tags');
    $query -> join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'tags.user_creative_id' );
    $query -> join('tag_post', 'tag_post.tag_id', '=', 'tags.id' )
           ->select('tags.*', 
                     DB::raw('(SELECT count(*) FROM tag_post WHERE tags.id = tag_post.tag_id )  as count_posts')    
            )
           ->orderBy('count_posts','desc')
           ->groupBy('tags.id');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [LeftJoin](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#left-join-right-join-clause) to show all rows from left table that doing join:

```
 $query = DB::table('tags');
    $query -> join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'tags.user_creative_id' );
    $query -> leftJoin('tag_post', 'tag_post.tag_id', '=', 'tags.id' )
           ->select('tags.*', 
                     DB::raw('(SELECT count(*) FROM tag_post WHERE tags.id = tag_post.tag_id )  as count_posts')    
            )
           ->orderBy('count_posts','desc')
           ->groupBy('tags.id');
```

Comment: this solved my problem, thanks a lot